# Calling a Swift function from Objective-C class

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c

I'm trying to call a Swift function from an Objective-C class
and it's throwing:

```
No visible @interface for 'TUtils' declares the selector 'run'
```

TUtils.swift

```swift
@objc
public class TUtils: NSObject  {
    
    @objc func run() {
        print("Hello test")
    }
}
```

Consume.m

```
#import <RKit/RKit-Swift.h>
    
inline int tempFun () {
    TUtils *obj = [TUtils new];
    [obj run];
    return 0;
}
```

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Typical issue is that functions need to be `public` in order to be visible by Objective-C. [As docs say](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/importing-swift-into-objective-c):

> By default, the generated header contains interfaces for Swift declarations marked with the public or open modifier. If your app target has an Objective-C bridging header, the generated header also includes interfaces marked with the internal modifier.

So try to change your function to

```
@objc public func run() {
```

and see if this helps. If it does not, clear and rebuild from scratch. You can also open `RKit-Swift.h` (by command+click on it) and check how `TUtils` was declared and which functions Objective-C sees.

Comment: Thanks setting public before the function, solved my issue

Comment: Great, if you accept the answer, it can be referred by others then. Cheers!